# Error while finding duplicates by name

Tags: c++, duplicates

I have written a program which would find duplicates by name.
Eg:Lets say we have file a.txt,b.txt,c.txt in various directories.I need to find the files which are duplicated only by their name.The output would be the filename which are present in various directories.

Code:

```
fs::path tempHolder;
int isDuplicate=0;//To check whether duplicate or not.
vec::const_iterator tempit (v.begin());//i already have vector v which has all the filenames
for (vec::const_iterator it (v.begin()); it != v.end();)
{

   tempHolder=*it;
   isDuplicate=0;
   tempit=it;
   while((++tempit)!=v.end() && tempHolder==(*(++it)))
   {
      isDuplicate=1;
   }
   if(isDuplicate==1)
   {
      cout<<"Duplicate:"<<tempHolder<<endl;
   }
 }
```

The problem is the for loop is going recursively but it prints the duplicate filename properly.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This loop seems strange to me:

```
tempit=it;
while((++tempit)!=v.end() && tempHolder==(*(++it)))
{
    isDuplicate=1;
}
```

If `it` is the last valid iterator of the container, the first condition will be false, so short-circuit evaluation will cause `++it` to never be executed. The loop will run indefinitely.

```
while((++tempit)!=v.end() && tempHolder==*tempit)
```

should work.

Comment: I have following folder structure:duplicate[folder]=dup1[folder]+a.txt+b.txt+e.txt;dup1[folder]=dup2[folder]+a.txt+b.txt+c.txt+d.txt+e.txt;dup2[folder]=b.txt+c.txt.If I follow your code,I am ending up in following output=a.txt,b.txt,b.txt,c.txt,e.txt.But I need following output=a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,e.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
while((++tempit)!=v.end() && tempHolder==(*(++it)))
```

You manipulate your iterator that you use in your big loop (it)
Better:

```
while((++tempit)!=v.end() && tempHolder==(*tempit))
```

If I understand your code correctly.

Edit: And your `it` needs to be incremented in your first loop.

I personally would rather write something like that:

```
while ((++tempit)!= v.end())
    if (*tempit = *it)
    {
        duplicate = true;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But I also need the how many files are duplicate.Thats why I am not breaking from the loop.

Comment: Ok, then dont break and increment the duplicate variable. `duplicate++;`

Comment: I have following folder structure:duplicate[folder]=dup1[folder]+a.txt+b.txt+e.txt;dup1[folder]=dup2[fol‌​der]+a.txt+b.txt+c.txt+d.txt+e.txt;dup2[folder]=b.txt+c.txt.If I follow your code,I am ending up in following output=a.txt,b.txt,b.txt,c.txt,e.txt.But I need following output=a.txt,b.txt,c.txt,e.txt

Comment: If I understand you correct you want a duplicate to just show up once. so if there is b.txt, b.txt and b.txt you wants b.txt just once in your duplicate list. Right? Then use a `std::set<std::string> duplicates`. Insert if you find a duplicate. And after finishing just iterate over the set and print it out.

Comment: A `std::set<T>` holds just one distinct item. So if you insert "a" twice, the set just save "a" once.